# Windows form to be shown topmost from taskbar

Tags: vb.net, winforms, taskbar

Using VB.NET I create a form with `TopMost=True`, `FormBorderStyle=FixedDialog`, `ControlBox=False`, `text=""`, `size 400x50`.
I display this form above Windows 10 taskbar. When I click on the taskbar, the form occupies only a taskbar's portion, the form is moved behind the taskbar. The form remains topmost if it is moved on the working area of the screen.
Is there a way to keep the form topmost above Windows 10 taskbar?
Sample code is given below. Using the arrows keys the form can be relocated for testing.

***UPDATE   sample code added.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Dim istep As Integer = 1
    If e.Alt Then istep = 10
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Down
            Me.Top += istep
        Case Keys.Up
            Me.Top -= istep
        Case Keys.Left
            Me.Left -= istep
        Case Keys.Right
            Me.Left += istep
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim b As Rectangle = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds
    Dim w As Rectangle = My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea

    Me.Top = w.Height
    Me.Left = 500
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the dialog manually according to the screen size in the `Load` function of the form.
The code would look something like (posting c# code):

```
    Location = new Point(0, 0);
    TopMost = true;
    var screen = Screen.FromHandle(Handle);
    Size = new Size(screen.Bounds.Width, screen.Bounds.Height);
```